# Pull ALL files from git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

Is it possible to locally cache ALL files in a git-LFS repo for offline use? That is, make the repo usable like a normal git repo, even without an internet connection to fetch git-LFS files?

Comment: Here is a related Q&A I just posted: [What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, and `git lfs pull`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72610494/4561887)

Answer (score 79):

Yes! You can download all LFS files with the following command:

`git lfs fetch --all`

Check out the documentation for this feature here:

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn

Comment: I'd add a caution: this retrieves all copies of the lfs-stored binaries (all historical versions, reached on any branch), not just the ones you need right now (the --all flag could bring in a lot more than you really intend).  I just want current binaries to use while in the cave, not historical, and I'm limiting my download to a branch like `git lfs fetch origin master`.

Comment: That should be the default behaviour of LFS. In fact `git fetch origin master` should accomplish what you want if LFS is behaving correctly. The original question wanted ALL files cached so they could use the the repo like a normal git repo. In that situation you do need all historical versions of binaries.

Answer (score 18):

#### Local git to retrieve the latest meta-data

```
git lfs fetch --all
```

#### Brings (copy) the changes from the remote repository

```
git lfs pull
```

Comment: I was really struggling to understand what `git lfs fetch` does, vs `git lfs fetch --all`, `git lfs pull`, and `git lfs checkout`, as they were super confusing, so I just did the study & posted this Q&A: [What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, `git lfs pull`, and `git lfs checkout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887).

Comment: Thanks for also putting the command to copy the changes, that really speeds up the search because is the next obvious thing to do.